Formality in concession
In real language, what is the difference in formality between however, yet and still when used to express concession?

still is informal.  yet can appear in formal or informal contexts. however wears a shirt and tie so you don't use it in animated conversations about the sort of staged entertainment wrestling where one of the wrestlers hits the other over the head with a folding chair.

And the aspect of strength is 'still' the first; 'yet' the second; 'but' the third; 'however' the fourth. 'however' is the weakest in meaning but the strongest in formality.
